# How to Save All Row values of a gridview at single click in ASP

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datagridview

Hello i am trying to save all gridview values at single save click.

Here is my code i have tried.

```
protected void imgbtnSave_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
     // DAL and Other Code here

 foreach (GridViewRow row in gvServicePort.Rows)
    {
      Label _lblOneID = gvServicePort.Rows[row.RowIndex].FindControl("lblOneID") as Label;
        objserRtnDtls.TerminalID = Convert.ToInt16(_lblOneID .Text);

     RadioButton _lblTwo = gvServicePort.Rows[row.RowIndex].FindControl("rdDirectPOL") as RadioButton;   

         if (_lblIsPOL.Checked == true)
            objserRtnDtls.IsPOL = true;
        else
            objserRtnDtls.IsPOL = false;  
         int i = dalSPM.ServicePort_Update(objserRtnDtls, objSerRtn);
}
```

But here for the first two iteration iam getting return value as 1 later its 0 and its not getting saved in DB

Comment: try checking first if it is a data row: `row.RowType==DataControlRowType.DataRow`

Comment: Can you please elaborate that code

Comment: just wrap the body of your `foreach` loop with `if(row.RowType==DataControlRowType.DataRow)`

Answer (score 0):

One issue may be that _lblTwo is never used to populate objserRtnDtls. I'm assuming it was probably intended to be _lblIsPOL. I've adjusted the code below based on that assumption.

I also included the check for DataRow per the comment above (excellent point mshsayem).

```
protected void imgbtnSave_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    // DAL and Other Code here

    foreach (GridViewRow row in gvServicePort.Rows)
    {
        if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            // wire up the controls in this row
            Label _lblOneID = (Label)row.FindControl("lblOneID");
            RadioButton _rdIsPOL = (RadioButton)row.FindControl("rdDirectPOL"); // renamed _lblTwo to _rdIsPOL

            // load the control data into your object
            objserRtnDtls.TerminalID = Convert.ToInt16(_lblOneID.Text);
            objserRtnDtls.IsPOL = _rdIsPOL.Checked; // renamed _lblIsPOL to _rdIsPOL to match the RadioButton above

            // attempt to update the database
            int i = dalSPM.ServicePort_Update(objserRtnDtls, objSerRtn);
        }
    }
}
```

The other issue is that you may want to consider resetting objserRtnDtls at the end of each foreach iteration so you don't accidentally leave old data from the last line in the object. If you have duplicate data and try an insert it may fail if TerminalID is supposed to be unique in your database. I don't know what objSerRtn does so you will have to judge for yourself there.